# C# | Forms .NET | How can I make a ComboBox that show's Excel sheets which it then displays in the dataViewGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, visual-studio-code

So I have been working on a little application for a bit and its pretty enjoyable so far. You can pick any Excel file you want and any Access Database you want and then save the Excel data to it. It also displays the Excel data in the dataGridview. Eventually I want to be able to change data in the Gridview it self and be able to save that as well, but that's for another time. right now I'd like to know how I can make a ComboBox that lets me pick the Sheet of my Excel file.

My current GUI looks like this:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag5yI.png)

Item Names:

```
btnrun - "Runs" the excel file in the datagridview
btnbrowse - chooses which Excel file you want to use
btnbrowse2 - chooses which Access Database file you want to use
btnsave - saves Excel data to Access Database
textBox1 - Shows the file path for Excel
textBox2 - Shows the file path for Access Database
comboBox1 - This is where i need help :)
dataGridView1 - Shows the Excel data
```

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Datatestje
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //Buttons
        private void btnrun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Run
        {
            string EXpath = textBox1.Text;
            string PathConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + EXpath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);

            var sqlQuery = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Save
        {
            {
                //File Path
                string EXpath = textBox1.Text;
                string fileNameExcel = @EXpath;
                string ACpath = textBox2.Text;
                string fileNameAccess = @ACpath;

                //Connection string for Excel
                string connectionStringExcel =
                    string.Format("Data Source= {0};Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileNameExcel);

                //Connection string for Access
                string ConnectionStringAccess =
                    string.Format("Data Source= {0}; Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist security Info = false", fileNameAccess);

                OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringExcel);
                OleDbConnection connAccess = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringAccess);
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = connExcel.CreateCommand();
                cmdExcel.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                //Excel Sheet
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

                //Command object for Access
                OleDbCommand cmdAccess = connAccess.CreateCommand();
                cmdAccess.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                
                //Add parameters *
                cmdAccess.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Informatie (Naam, Achternaam, Land, Stad, Huisnummer, Postcode, Telefoonnummer) VALUES(@Naam, @Achternaam, @Land, @Stad, @Huisnummer, @Postcode, @Telefoonnummer)";

                //Add parameters to Access command object **
                OleDbParameter param1 = new OleDbParameter("@Naam", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param1);
                OleDbParameter param2 = new OleDbParameter("@Achternaam", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param2);
                OleDbParameter param3 = new OleDbParameter("@Land", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param3);
                OleDbParameter param4 = new OleDbParameter("@Stad", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param4);
                OleDbParameter param5 = new OleDbParameter("@Huisnummer", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param5);
                OleDbParameter param6 = new OleDbParameter("@Postcode", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param6);
                OleDbParameter param7 = new OleDbParameter("@Telefoonnummer", OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmdAccess.Parameters.Add(param7);


                //Open connections
                connExcel.Open();
                connAccess.Open();
                OleDbDataReader drExcel = cmdExcel.ExecuteReader();

                while (drExcel.Read())
                {
                    //Assign values to access command parameters ***
                    param1.Value = drExcel[0].ToString();
                    param2.Value = drExcel[1].ToString();
                    param3.Value = drExcel[2].ToString();
                    param4.Value = drExcel[3].ToString();
                    param5.Value = drExcel[4].ToString();
                    param6.Value = drExcel[5].ToString();
                    param7.Value = drExcel[6].ToString();

                    //Insert values in access
                    cmdAccess.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                //close connections
                connAccess.Close();
                connExcel.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Succesfully uploaded Excel data to Database.");

            }
        }

        private void btnbrowse_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfiledialog1.ShowDialog();
            openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.xls";
            textBox1.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
        }

        private void btnbrowse2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfiledialog1.ShowDialog();
            openfiledialog1.Filter = "allfiles|*.mdb";
            textBox2.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

So, yeah. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Congratulations on your success so far!  What part are you stuck on? How to list the sheets? How to fill a combo box?

Comment: I have never used a comboBox before so I have no clue how to add it in so that I can select the Excel sheets from it.

Comment: As in: how can i get the Sheet names in the ComboBox and how can I make it so that when I select a Sheet from the drop down menu it opens the Sheet's information in the dataGridView.

Comment: Also, I know I have `var sqlQuery = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";` in my code. But that is simply there because I've been slowly expanding the application from a 1 button thing to an actual application with multiple functions. So I know I'll need to replace that but I don't yet know with what. I already tried some pieces of code I found online but they sadly didn't work.

Comment: How is it going?  Did AVG's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get sheet names via:

```
DataTable dtSheets = conn.GetSchema("Tables")
```

You can find how to populate a ComboBox with a simple Google search.
You can populate your DataTable with the sheet contents simply by substituting 'Sheet1$' with the name of the selected sheet

```
 var sqlQuery = "Select * from [" + strSheetName + "]";
```

Comment: So would that be something along the lines of: 
`private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtSheets = conn.GetSchema("Tables")
            var sqlQuery = "Select * from [" + strSheetName + "]";
        }`

Comment: No. GetSchema is used to populate a DataTable with the list of sheets. That is what you want to populate your ComboBox with. You can't use the SelectedIndexChanged event to populate the ComboBox because there won't be entries. You should populate the ComboBox after the user selects a file. Then populate your grid after the user selects an entry from the ComboBox.